# Do I Need to close the handle if I don't store the return value of GetModuleHandle?

Tags: winapi

I was wondering if I had to close the handle if for example I were to call `GetModuleHandle` this way

```
GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("modulename"),  "nameoftheexportedfunction")
```

what would be the proper way to close the handle? Do I need to do

```
HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle("modulename"); 
GetProcAddress(hModule, "nameoftheexportedfunction")
CloseHandle(hModule);
```

Or does it get deleted automatically if the value returned by `GetModuleHandle` isn't stored into a variable?

Answer (score 10):

[GetModuleHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683199.aspx) returns an `HMODULE` (aka `HINSTANCE` - see [What is the difference between HINSTANCE and HMODULE?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040614-00/?p=38903)). This data type cannot be passed to [CloseHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211.aspx).

The `HMODULE` could be passed to [FreeLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683152.aspx) but that is not required either, since `GetModuleHandle` doesn't increase the reference count on the module. In fact, calling `FreeLibrary` might cause the module to get unmapped prematurely, leading to a spectacular crash.

In short: `GetModuleHandle` returns a read-only value, that doesn't need to be disposed off in any way. The first line of code in your question is fine.

Answer (score 4):

The Windows API can be very confusing in this respect, as there are multiple things called a handle, and they all have different rules.

In this case, `CloseHandle` closes kernel handles, which typically refer to files or other kernel resources such as synchronization objects that are created with a name—which all are identified by being returned as a `HANDLE`.

`GetModuleHandle` returns an `HMODULE`—actually the base address of a loaded EXE or DLL—and, as it is not a `HANDLE`, does not need to be, and *must* not be, released with `CloseHandle`.

As @David Heffernan points out, this does not mean other handle types never have their own destroy/release/un-acquire semantics, and it also does not mean that every `HANDLE` you get from an API must be passed to `CloseHandle` either. There is just no substitute for knowing the specific API you are dealing with and its particular handle management requirements.

Comment: LoadLibrary returns an HMODULE that should be released with FreeLibrary. Kernel handles are not the only things that must be released.